# Django-tinymce working with "manage.py renserver", but not served by apache2

Tags: python, django, apache, tinymce

The mce does not appears when running under apache: I get texaereas.

In both cases (running with "runserver" and with apache, on two different machines, I have django-tinymce installed in the vitualenv.

In the form.py file I have:

```
from django.forms import TextInput, Textarea
from tinymce.widgets import TinyMCE
```

And

```
class myform(forms.Form): 
    titre=forms.CharField(label="titre",help_text=help,
                          required=True,
                          widget =TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 50, 'rows': 4}
```

And in my template html file:

```
<head>
...
{{ form.media }}
</head>
```

Then:

```
<table class="table table-sm">
        {{ form.as_table }}
      </table>
```

No idea of what happens...

Comment: first you could check JavaScript console in `DevTools` in Chrome/Firefox - maybe there are some error messages. You could also check tab `Network` in `DevTools` to see if it reads all files - maybe it has problem to read JavaScript files. `runsever` may send static files (.js, .css, images) for you (to make easy to test server) but when you run with `apache`/`nginx` then you have to configure  `apache`/`nginx` to send static files.

Comment: Mhh,yes. I am looking for tinymce js files in <root of django site>/static which is served by Apache as /static (Alias /static/...) and tinymce js files are not there. I fixed this by copying django_tinymce/ and tinymce/ there.  It works! 
But there is certainly a much cleaner way to do this.

Comment: keeping all static files in folder `/static` is a much cleaner way.